# Handling enum default value as action parameter

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, url-routing

I have enum that looks like:

```
public enum MyUrls
{
    Url1 = 0,       
    Url2 = 1,       
    Url3 = 2
}
```

I'm using it to generate urls for some pages on my website.
Base url looks like `www.mysite.com/part/`, also i got 3 routes:

```
www.mysite.com/part/Url1
www.mysite.com/part/Url2
www.mysite.com/part/Url3
```

The last parameter of query string is generated using UrlHelper.

Controller action looks like:

```
public ActionResult MyPage(MyUrls parameter = MyUrls.Url1)
{       
    return View("MyView");
}
```

input parameter of action has default value to make url `www.mysite.com/part` work. All other routes work well as expected.

The question is: How can i handle urls like `www.mysite.com/part/not_existent_enum_value` - it should return `HttpNotFound` result, and still keep page `www.mysite.com/part/` as a default one

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks for attention, got my own answer:

```
public ActionResult MyPage(string parameter)
{
    var parameterValue = MyUrls.Url1;
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(parameter) && !Enum.TryParse(parameter, out parameterValue))
        return HttpNotFound();
    return View("MyView");
}
```

`parameterValue` will contain default value for routing. If `parameter` passed to action is invalid enum value we throw error 404

Answer (score 4):

Make the enum type nullable:

```
public ActionResult MyPage(MyUrls? parameter = MyUrls.Url1)
{
    if (!parameter.HasValue) {
       return HttpNotFound();
    }
    return View("MyView");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could try to use a `IModelBinder`

```
public class MyUrlsEnumModelBinder : IModelBinder
{
    public object BindModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
    {
        var valueResult = bindingContext.ValueProvider.GetValue(bindingContext.ModelName);

        MyUrls temp;

        if (!Enum.TryParse(valueResult.AttemptedValue, out temp))
            return MyUrls.Url1;
        return temp;
    }
}
```

And within your Global.asax.cs:

```
    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        /*  */
        ModelBinders.Binders.Add(typeof(MyUrls), new MyUrlsEnumModelBinder());
    }
```

This will always set the value to `MyUrls.Url1` if it is a invalid value. You controlleraction can be as followed:

```
  public ActionResult MyPage(MyUrls url)
```

Comment: Almost there, but i need to throw 404 if model is invalid enum value. Thanks for attention, posted my own answer below - it looks more simple and explicit.

Answer (score 0):

In your action:

```
public ActionResult MyPage(MyUrls parameter = MyUrls.Url1)
{       

   if( Enum.IsDefined(typeof(MyUrls), parameter ) )
   {
      //redirect your not found url
   }

    return View("MyView");
}
```

Comment: aint good. Parameter will be always MyUrls.Url1 if i pass wrong value to action